# Different values in JQuery UI Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

Is it possible to create my own steps in jquery UI slider?
For example, I have 5 steps: 0, 1200, 2000, 2200 and 3000. Somebody know how to do this?

```
const rangeSliderInit = () => {
const valueArray = [0, 400, 1000, 1500, 2000, 3000, 420
$(".slider").slider({
value: 400,
min: 0,
max: 4200,
});
}
```

Comment: Put the values you want in an array, then set the slider to have as many steps as the length of the array. When the slider value is changed, get the value from the array at the current index. If you want more specific help and some examples, please edit your question to show your current code.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of displaying the right value (it can be something else in reality).

Create an array of the values. Set max value to the amount of options in your array and step 1.

Here i just make the sliders min=0 and max = 4, with a step of 1.

You can use sizes[ui.value] as your value of the slider.

On changing the slider value

```js
var sizes = [0, 1200, 2000, 2200, 3000];
$("#slider").slider({
  min: 0,
  max: sizes.length - 1,
  step: 1,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#slider-value").text(sizes[ui.value]);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<h1>HTML Slider Test</h1>

<div id="slider"></div>

<p>Your slider has a value of <span id="slider-value"></span></p>
```